# How to find a Rect closest to a given Rect from a list of them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have a function which prints out a list of Rects like this

```
[<rect(394, 28, 80, 100)>, <rect(394, 126, 80, 100)>, <rect(394, 224, 80, 100)>, <rect(472, 28, 80, 100)>, <rect(472, 126, 80, 100)>]
```

and I'm looking for a way to match the closest Rect from the list above to any given Rect.

For eg, a given Rect like this one `<rect(377, 231, 50, 70)>` would match with `<rect(394, 224, 80, 100)>` and print it out.

I've tried doing that with tuple and list of tuples by using min function like this

```
temp_list = [(1, 3), (4, 9), (5, 7), (3, 5), (9, 4), (8, 4), (6, 1)]
temp_tuple = (5, 11)

nearest = min(temp_list, key=lambda c: (c[0] - temp_tuple[0]) ** 2 + (c[1] - temp_tuple[1]) ** 2)

print(nearest)
```

but I don't know how I'd make it work for Rect data type.

Comment: You have the right idea of what to do in Python, your problem is that it's not well defined what the distance between two rects is. Should it be the distance between the centers? The average distance between the corners? The average distance between the sides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, using the distance between the centres as the decider:

```
import math

distance = 1000

current_cx = current_rect.centerx
current_cy = current_rect.centery

for rect in rect_list:
    cx = rect.centerx
    cy = rect.centery

    if math.sqrt(abs(current_cx-cx)**2 + abs(current_cy-cy)**2)) < distance:
        nearest_rect = rect
```